# modal window changes some rows in table instead of one

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with some rows. Table rows can be modified by ajax requests. Modifying happens in a modal widnow for the current row (just for one).

So, I found a bug. I click `edit` for 1st line. I see the modal window with values of 1st line. So, it's ok. Then I click `close` without saving. Well. I click `edit` for 2nd line. I see the modal window with values of 2nd line. So, it's ok too. Now, if I click `Save changes`, I see two modified rows (1st and 2nd), but it seems just 2nd row must be modified. If I do the same for N count of rows I see N changed rows.

I don't understand why it's happen. Can anybody explain me?

https://jsfiddle.net/bogdan_017/26gaqpcf/#&togetherjs=C1ltBspbSs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you click on an edit, you ADD another click event to the save button ... in this code `modal.find(".save-btn").click(function () {`

you need to remove the click event on the save button once you click on it

```
// snip
modal.modal('hide');
$(this).off('click'); // add this here
// snip
```

You'll also need to handle the modal close (the close button) and remove the click event on the save button in that case